# How can I make the particles in my SKEmitterNode opaque?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I've experimented a lot with the settings in the Particle Emitter editor, but none of them seem to allow me to actually make the particles completely opaque.  I've also tried editing it in the actual code:

```
if let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ToothExplosion") {
            explosion.particleColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
            explosion.particleColorBlendFactor = 1.0;
            explosion.particleColorSequence = nil;
            explosion.position = contactPoint
            addChild(explosion)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the Particle Texture?

Try to put (in your sks file, `ToothExplosion.sks`) a solid circle, spark is not opaque:

[image]

Comment: No, he has his own texture he is using

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I think you don't understand what Simone Pistecchia say: try to put a solid circle ( in other words perhaps your texture is not opaque). This probability could be true as you added in your answer below (Any other transparency is happening due to the texture)

Comment: He asked did the OP change the particular texture because  spark is not opaque, and to use a solid color, to which you agree.  This means that Simone Piestecchia missed the code where he is using his own texture, which means his question as an answer is already answered.  This also means that we should assume that the OP is smart enough to not use a texture that has transparency, because it would be silly to ask  SO this type of question if this was the case, so now this answer holds 0 value to the question at hand.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon How do you know that he is using his own texture?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia look at his code,  you know what,  you are right,  That is an SKS file,  we have no idea what he is doing, do a small edit to this so that I may change my vote to neutral again

Comment: Yes, I am already using my own texture, which I was certain was opaque by looking at it, but this made me take another look and it actually wasn't.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `particleAlpha` start to 1 and the `particleAlphaRange` to 0.  This will allow for the alpha to always be 1 without changing.  Any other transparency is happening due to the texture.